# Place BoxWhiskerChart onto plot

Tags: plotting, charts

Suppose I have two plots: one which is a generic curve, the other is a box whisker chart of data. How can I overlay the two (with the outliers removed)?

```
randGen = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 100}];
p1 = Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
BoxWhiskerChart[randGen,
 "Outliers",
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel",
 FrameLabel -> {"", "x"}]
```

If possible, is it easy to invert the axis of the box-whisker chart so that the y-axis becomes the x-axis? The y-coordinate of the box plots will be fed by a list.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine two plots by using `Show`:

```
randGen = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 100}];
p1 = Plot[1 - x/10, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
p2 = BoxWhiskerChart[randGen, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
   FrameLabel -> {"", "x"}];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: Combining two plots.]

Note that I have scaled the curve and changed the range. To hide the outliers, I have removed `"Outliers"`.

To swap the axes, use the option `BarOrigin`:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[randGen, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", BarOrigin -> Right]
```

[image: Swaping axes.]

However, the boxes will be stacked one on another with the spacing that you can control with the option `BarSpacing`. There seems to be no easy way to manually provide the $y$ coordinates of the boxes.